# How to change alert(var) label from "this page says". I want to change the "this page says?

Tags: javascript, alert

I have alert(var); that produces a pop-up box that displays "This page says:" and the displays my var text string perfectly. But I am also trying to change the text of "This page says:" property of the alert box.